# Easier method for writing to files

Tags: php

Is there a better way of doing this?:

```
$dataString2 = " $leder klarte orgkrim å fikk: ".$showcah." den ".$timed." ";
$dataString3 = " $hacker klarte orgkrim å fikk: ".$showcah." den ".$timed." ";
$dataString4 = " $driver klarte orgkrim å fikk: ".$showcah." den ".$timed." ";
$dataString5 = " $weaponexpert klarte orgkrim å fikk: ".$showcah." den ".$timed." ";
$dataStringinfo = "$leder, $hacker, $driver, $weaponexpert klarte å OC med å få ".$showcah." tid: ".$timed.""; 
$dataStringinfo .= "\n";
$dataString2 .= "\n";
$dataString3 .= "\n";
$dataString4 .= "\n";
$dataString5 .= "\n";
$fWrite0 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/completed/oversikt.txt","a");
$fWrite1 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/oversikt.txt","a");
$fWrite2 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/completed/$leder.txt","a");
$fWrite3 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/completed/$hacker.txt","a");
$fWrite4 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/completed/$driver.txt","a");
$fWrite5 = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/completed/$weaponexpert.txt","a");

$wrote2 = fwrite($fWrite2, $dataString2);
$wrote2 = fwrite($fWrite3, $dataString3);
$wrote3 = fwrite($fWrite4, $dataString4);
$wrote4 = fwrite($fWrite5, $dataString5);
$wrote5 = fwrite($fWrite1, $dataStringinfo);
$wrote0 = fwrite($fWrite0, $dataStringinfo);
fclose($fWrite0);
fclose($fWrite1);
fclose($fWrite2);
fclose($fWrite3);
fclose($fWrite4);
fclose($fWrite5);
```

In short, this sends the various "logs" different places. I wonder if there is any easier way to do this here, to save space.

Comment: It looks like part of what you are doing can be reconfigured into a loop

Comment: A loop. A user defined function. A logger class.

Comment: maybe take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework

Comment: you can just use `$wrote2 = fwrite($fWrite2, 'content directly');`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments above indicated using a logger class, but I think for this isolated example that would be overkill.

Note that much of your code is doing the same thing for each different file: `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`.  This sequence of function calls would be an ideal candidate for turning into a function. Luckily for you, that function already exists: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
$common = " klarte orgkrim å fikk: ".$showcah." den ".$timed." \n";

$dataString2 = " $leder" . $common;
$dataString3 = " $hacker" . $common;
$dataString4 = " $driver" . $common;
$dataString5 = " $weaponexpert" . $common;
$dataStringinfo = "$leder, $hacker, $driver, $weaponexpert klarte å OC med å få ".$showcah." tid: ".$timed."\n"; 

$logdir = "/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/";

file_put_contents($logdir."/completed/oversikt.txt", $dataStringinfo, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($logdir."/oversikt.txt", $dataStringinfo, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($logdir."/completed/$leder.txt", $dataString2, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($logdir."/completed/$hacker.txt", $dataString3, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($logdir."/completed/$driver.txt", $dataString4, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($logdir."/completed/$weaponexpert.txt", $dataString5, FILE_APPEND);
```

---

Note that I removed many lines by simply changing:

```
$foo = "bla".$bar." ";
$foo .= "\n";
```

to

```
$foo = "bla".$bar." \n";
```

---

Comment: Could you give one example ? ( with some of them or spoonfeed me a little bit more?)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Another question, which you see is part of the "messages" over and over again, just with a different variable. Is it possible 1 line code or something of which goes through the variables of a specific string or variable?

eg

$ spec = $ driver, $ head, (whatever);

echo "bla bla bla bla (and which retrieves spec, sending a line out for the driver, a new one for leads, etc etc?).

Excuse my terrible english, but you understand what I'm trying to ask here?

Comment: I've simplified it even more by pulling out the common part of those strings into the variable `$common`.

Comment: anyway to do for example:
$driver = Malin;
$leder = Jonathon;
$person = bob;
$name = $driver, $leder, $person;
echo "hello $name";

output:
hello Malin
Hello Jonathon
Hello bob

if you understand? sorry to bothering you btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using loops, like:

```
$dsA[0] = $dsA[1] = "$leder, $hacker, $driver, $weaponexpert klarte å OC med å få $showcah tid: $timed \n";
$dsV = array($leder, $hacker, $driver, $weaponexpert);
for($i=2; $i<6; $i++){
  $dsA[$i] = " $dsV[$i] klarte orgkrim å fikk: $showcah den $timed \n";
}
$cp = 'completed';
$fwS = array('oversikt.txt', "$cp/oversikt.txt", "$cp/$leder.txt", "$cp/$hacker.txt", "$cp/$driver.txt", "$cp/$weaponexpert.txt");
foreach($fwS as $i => $v){
  $fp = fopen("/home/nordic/www/logger/orgkrim/$v", 'a');
  fwrite($fp, $dsA[$i]); fclose($fp);
}
```

Sorry, I don't speak your language.

Comment: Well, i now it sends the message for example the leder gets the message for the hacker too. I would like it for the leader to get only one thats with the $leader, and so on. except oversikt ( both) to include : "$leder, $hacker, $driver, $weaponexpert klarte å OC med å få $showcah tid: $timed"

Comment: if you use these variables with it:
$leder = miss;
$hacker = miss2;
$driver = miss3;
$weaponexpert = miss4;
$showcah = 100;
$timed = date('d/m/Y - H:ia');

you get this:  miss3 klarte orgkrim å fikk: 100 den 24/07/2013 - 01:26am in miss2`s file. and so on. And two of them are "blank" names.

Comment: I think I fixed it. Try again.

Comment: Are you willing to teamviewer me?:)

Comment: I can chat with you here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34023/phpglue .

Comment: Is it somewhere else?
You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.